# Pass a @selector between classes, calling the method from an instanced Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, selector, subclass

I have a viewController with a method: doSomething:. I have a class Menu that sets up a menu with a button, on which I have "added a target" so I can call a selector from the button. This subclass is instanced from the viewController.

When I tap the instanced menu's button I would like to call the method in the viewController. The obvious way to set this up would be to add an observer to NSNotifications, but seems kind of klunky. Can I somehow pass the selector from the view controller to the instance like so:

in Menu.h

```
-(void)setupMenuWithAction:(SEL)action {
```

called from the ViewController:

```
[menu setupMenuWithAction:@selector(doSomething:)];
```

Tried it and it does not work, gives unrecognized selector error when the button is tapped, but I'm wondering if it is a valid concept, and if so how can I fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the method in `Menu.h` to include a target -- make it `-(void)setupMenuWithAction:(SEL)action andTarget:(id)target`. Within that method, call the selector with `[target performSelector:action];`

Then, from the `ViewController`, call `[menu setupMenuWithAction:@selector(doSomething:) andTarget:self];`

Comment: very interesting, but not sure how to add the bit: [object performSelector:action];... the method setupMenuWithAction: just makes a button and adds a target with the selector. Do I make another method to call performSelector:? sorry, being dense.

Comment: @Mrwolfy Not a problem; didn't realize you wanted to directly add it as the action for a button. Use this -- ```[myButton addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];```

Comment: OK, yeah that makes total sense, and I did that. Still gives me the unknown selector error though.

Comment: @Mrwolfy Just went over it and it looks good to me. Just to be clear, ```doSomething:``` is a method in the View Controller, right?

Comment: yep, I double checked that. Triple checking now.

Comment: strangely, maybe, it works just fine if I add the target to the instanced button directly from the vc. Just seems less clean way to code it.

Comment: Ahh got it now. used this (addTarget:object) to add the target!         [button addTarget:object action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: @Mrwolfy Got it. I edited it after posting changing ```object``` to ```target``` (because that's what Apple's documentation calls it). You must have used some bits of the original code combined with some bits of the new code :)

Answer (score 0):

For the function in the class that has the actual selector, use '+' instead of '-'. i.e. use the class method instead of instance method